# REST xml answer - Jaxb - Amazon product API

Tags: java, rest, jakarta-ee, jaxb, amazon-product-api

I'm currently (trying) to work with the amazon product API to search thourgh items.
I have the response in XML, but i have an exception in jaxb, maybe i missed something..

Here is the XML :

[XML response from Amazon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xlxbb.png)

I want to extract items informations, but i'm getting some trouble.

Item class:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="ItemSearchResponse")
public class AmazonItem
{
    private String name;
    private String asin;
    private String price;

    public AmazonItem()
    {

    }

    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(CollapsedStringAdapter.class)
    @XmlElement(name="Title")
    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(CollapsedStringAdapter.class)
    @XmlElement(name="ASIN")
    public String getAsin()
    {
        return asin;
    }
    public void setAsin(String asin)
    {
        this.asin = asin;
    }

    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(CollapsedStringAdapter.class)
    @XmlElement(name="FormattedPrice")
    public String getPrice()
    {
        return price;
    }
    public void setPrice(String price)
    {
        this.price = price;
    }
}
```

my builder :

```
public class AmazonItemBuilder
{
    public AmazonItemBuilder()
    {

    }

    public List<AmazonItem> build(InputStream response)
    {
        try
        {
            JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(AmazonItem.class);
            Unmarshaller unMarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();
            AmazonItem newItem = (AmazonItem) unMarshaller.unmarshal(response);
            System.out.println(newItem);
        }
        catch (JAXBException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

the "response" come from a URL response.openStream();

OK i forgot the error -**_**-
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: 
unexpected element (uri:"http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01", local:"ItemSearchResponse"). Expected elements are <{}ItemSearchResponse>

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the XML document is namespace qualified.  You can use the package level `@XmlSchema` location annotation to specify the namespace qualification for the entire document.  Package level annotations go on a special call called `package-info` that looks like the following:

**package-info**

```
@XmlSchema(
    namespace = "http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01",
    elementFormDefault = XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)
package com.your.pkg;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema;
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/08/jaxb-namespaces.html

Comment: @BVMR : It was my first thought.. but i thought there was a better solution.

Thanks i'll try this Blaise

Comment: Ok thanks, it solved the Exception problem ^^. Now the AmazonItem is created, but it's field is null.

Comment: @ogdabou - Your object model and mappings don't match the XML document you are trying to unmarshal.  If you marshal an instance of your objects you will be able to get a sense of what you currently have mapped.  If there is an XML Schema for the message you may find it easier to have JAXB generate the object model for you.

Answer (score 0):

I hope the top level class to covert the response to object should be "ItemSearchResponse", try creating a class with member variable "Items" which inturn will have another member object array "AmazonItem"